# fingerprint-gui on Linux Mint 19 "Tara" cinnamon works but not on first boot or in software center

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, encryption, pam, fingerprint

On my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd. Gen., fingerprint-gui works fine when locking the screen or requesting sudo in terminal.

It doesn't work when I freshly boot up the system at first login, and it doesn't work either when installing software from the apt software center over the GUI.

Is there a way I can change something so that this works with the fingerprint, too?

I must say that I've encrypted LVM partitions running, perhaps this is a reason why it doesn't work at boot time?

Attached is my `pam-update-auth` screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello and also thanks for the answer.
I also use Cinnamon and have already tried ubuntuusers.de instructions to my fingerprint reader to function to move.  But unfortunately it fails so far because the device is not supported or the daemon was not started to login. My FP reader apparently is not supported.

I also had a tutorial by Petre Boboc tried : https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495/blob/master/vfs495_ubuntu_18.04.md
but also does not work, the login is simply not queried after "Enter" the FP-Reader. The login window then always reports "wrong password ...."

if it works for you please give feedback.

Comment: It works for me in most cases, where it doesn't work is the very first login after booting and when installing software via the software center. Other things like sudo in terminal, locking the screen etc. are working.

Comment: Vielen Dank für ihre Revision. Aber inzwischen ist mit LinuxMint 21.3 Cinnamon mein Fingerprint immer noch nicht nutzbar. Das Gerät FP-Reader „VFS495 138a:003f“ wird nicht unterstützt.